# Change WAL directory in Open Source GreenPlum 6.x

Tags: database, database-administration, greenplum, wal

We are using **GreenPlum 6.x (Open Source)** and have to change the **WAL** directory as each segment has its own WAL directory so what can be the way forward to change the WAL directory in GreenPlum.

Comment: What's your rationale to change the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful to know the reason for changing the WAL directory. There is no tested method with all the functionalities for Greenplum for moving the WAL directory but for non-production to try out, can stop the cluster and symbolic link the pg_xlog directory for master and/or segments to some other location. This explains how can be accomplished for single node postgres https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+h6AhjCpQG8ydoCMgYX=1PHNut-RNbTt=r_K0O_Ktz7BFm7Sg@mail.gmail.com. Same needs to be done for all the nodes in Greenplum.